# Unable to get req.body.username in a post

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a login register system and experimenting as I'm new to NodeJS. For some reason (using the same lines of code) I can get the `req.body.password`. But not the `req.body.username`. When I but my login function in my register code works just fine. when the login code goes into the login function doesn't work.
Login HTML

Register HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
<br>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
<br>
<input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
```

Login NodeJS

```
  app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.body.user;
  var password = req.body.password;
  console.log(name);
```

Output is "undefined"

Register NodeJS

app.post('/register', async function(req, res) {

```
  let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 8); 
  console.log(hashedPassword);
  console.log(req.body.username);
```

This one outputs the username. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: have you added `body parser` middleware?

Comment: How are you sending the data from the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

In `var name = req.body.user;` should be `req.body.username`.

Comment: Yep. Happens to me as well haha

Comment: Some reason its not working anymore. No typos or anything. dunno what happend

Comment: What did you change? Create a new question and call me, I can try to help you again.